# Hola, xfavor alguien me podria dar una sugerencia para generar un subinforme rdlc en c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, rdlc

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Este es el el error del codigo:

[image]

Comment: Te sugiero que hagas caso de lo que dice el mensaje de error y revises los archivos de registro para obtener más información. Si con esa información no logras resolver, entonces agrega esa información a tu pregunta aquí, ya que sin ella, ni con las esferas del dragon se podría decir qué es lo que está pasando o como resolverlo :)

Comment: @MarcePuente respuesta? comentario?

Comment: @gbianchi-enhuelga, jaja, la sobrecarga me está matando... eliminado.

Comment: cuando la sobrecarga te mata, es mejor dar un paso al costado y descansar... @MarcePuente